# Wireguard Ubuntu Server Virtualmin FirewallD Connectivity

Tags: networking, server, iptables, wireguard

Does anyone know of any Ubunut Server 20.04 and/or Virtualmin related aspects that can interfere / block a wireguard connection?

**Problem:**
All settings verified as correct.  Client just can not connect.

**Things that I tried:**
1.) I have verified that the port (51820) is available and can be accessed through FirewallD GUI and by running:

(server side)
`nc -lu 51820`

(client side)
`echo Test message | nc -4u -w1   {host-ip} 51820`

And seeing "Test message" output on remote server.

2.) Under Webmin >> Webmin Configuration >> IP Access Control...   I have added both the wireguard client and server's addresses (i.e.  10.0.0.1 , 10.0.0.2)

3.) I have generated fresh key pairs on client and server. Putting client's pub key on the server and the Server's pub key on the client.

4.) I completely, disabled FirewalD and still could not connect, so FirewallD is an innocent party in this connection murder mystery.

I am asking here because I have literally the -identical- setup on a Debian Server (UFW not FirewallD & without Virtualmin) and it works perfectly.

There seems to be something related to Ubuntu and/or Virtualmin that is simply blocking the connection and I can't find any errors in `/var/log`

My `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` contains:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = server-private-key

[Peer]
PublicKey = client-public-key
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
```

And I edited `/etc/sysctl.conf` to have:
`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

From the client side when I connect, I get:

```
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.0.0.2/32 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg-client1
[#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0 -m 0 -x
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg-client1 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
[#] iptables-restore -n
```

And on the server I get this out put when I start wireguard:

```
# wg-quick up wg0 
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.0.0.1/24 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Everything is correct... the client just can't connect.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: i am using 20.04